# Exactly what ELSE needs to be done to make wso2 das 3.0.1 work with wso2 am 1.10.0?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+RDBMS) to the word, but nothing show up in publisher statistics.

From different sources, some mentioned that we have to download the .car file? But where is that .car file for apim? The one I got from github failed at deployment. Some mentioned that you have to leave empty all the fields in Data Analyzer Configurations section in admin-dashborad, contrary to what the above wso2 doc says.

No data published. No data ever written to the wso2am_stats_db data source. It's configured on both apim and das.

Excatly what ELSE needs to be done in addition to above wso2 doc to make both products work so apim publisher display usage statistics?

Comment: In api-manager.xml: why it mentions BAM??? (We know wso2 am 1.10.0 uses DAS by default) <Streams>
            ...
            <Destination>
                <Name>org_wso2_apimgt_statistics_destination</Name>
                <Version>1.0.0</Version>
                <BAMProfileName>bam-profile</BAMProfileName>
            </Destination>
           ...
        </Streams>

Comment: Here in wso2carbon.log, why it still mentions BAM? If BAM was disabled... does it mean DAS was disabled? IT's a mess       - TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-14 04:55:41,105]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.internal.StatisticsServiceComponent} -  BAM Service Stat Publishing is disabled {org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.internal.StatisticsServiceComponent}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was not clear in the wso2 doc is, I have to always deploy the apim .car file via carbon admin UI. After that, all works fine. (you may have to make sure binary data receiver has no port conflicts as well as as remove existing streamers)